# Can we have review queues expanded from the review link when hovering it?

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

I'd like to see the similar dropdown to the one which appears when you click "help" in the top bar...

[image]

but for the "review" link. Which could show the review queues and the number of tasks available in them. So as I wouldn't spend time clicking the review link - just hover and click the review queue I need.

Comment: Ohh very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

To satisfy my desire, I made a user script, which makes the drop down appear below the "review" link when you hover it.

This drop down shows only the queues which available to you according to your privileges. You can click any queue and, if it is not empty (which you can determine by looking at the number of available tasks left from the queue name, just like in the "big version"), you are taken directly to a review task.

There is how it looks like for me on Stack Overflow:

> [image: How it eventually looks]

### [Download this script!](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8709-mini-review-controller)

Comment: @Tim change ".hover()" to ".click()".

Comment: It is really unaligned for me:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCiz1.png Is that screen size issues?

Comment: @Tim Strange. It  is perfectly aligned for me on my Mac using 1920x1080 (pic in the answer from there) and my Samsung Galaxy S5 (http://i.stack.imgur.com/AHtsg.png).

Comment: Ohh shiny mac :P No, still misaligned even when i shrink the window...

Comment: @Tim and what did you install your script on? Tamper monkey or something else? (me tested just with tamper monkey). Not sure if it matters though...

Comment: Yeah, tampermonkey, chrome

Comment: @Tim eh, on the computer I tested just in Safari. Will look into it when I'll be back to my computer.

Comment: There we go, changed 650px to 615px. That's solved it here - maybe that's a requirement for chrome.

Comment: And now this is live in [so]!